# Selenium Wire Chrome driver losing internet connection

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am on Mac OS (macOS Catalina 10.15.5) and has chromedriver installed on `/usr/local/bin/chromedriver`.

I am using following code. I am facing the problem that chrome is losing the Internet connection in-between session.

```
import os

from selenium import webdriver
from seleniumwire import webdriver as wire_webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

profile_path ='/Users/doptimusprime/code/ProductionProfile/User_Data'
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options = wire_webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("user-data-dir="+profile_path)
options.add_argument('profile-directory=Default')
#options.add_argument('headless')
#options.add_argument('no-sandbox')
#options.add_argument('disable-dev-shm-usage')

driver = wire_webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="/usr/local/bin/chromedriver",chrome_options=options)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)
driver.get('https://admin.booking.com')
user_id = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "loginname")))
loginId = os.environ.get('LOGIN_ID')
password = os.environ.get('PASSWORD')
user_id.send_keys(loginId)
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'#root > div > div.access-container.bui_font_body > div > div.access-panel.bui-spacer--large.box-shadow.nw-access-panel > div.transition-container > div > div > div > form > div.bui-spacer > button > span'))).click()
secretKey = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "password")))
# AFTER THIS STEP, I AM LOSING INTERNET CONNECTION
secretKey.send_keys(password)
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,
                                           '#root > div > div.access-container.bui_font_body > div > div.access-panel.bui-spacer--large.box-shadow.nw-access-panel > div.transition-container > div > div > div > form > button > span'))).click()

cookies = driver.get_cookies()
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
urlr = driver.current_url
print("url is " + urlr)
```

After the above mentioned step, I opened a new tab and tried to open `google.com`. It was displaying `No Internet`. I tried disabling firewall. Still the problem persisted.

What is the reason of losing Internet connection in-between?

Edit: It seems that issue is with selenium wire webdriver. Without wire, it is working fine. Thanks @RahulL for pointing this out.

Comment: Are you facing same issue if seleniumwire  is not used ?

Comment: @RahulL It is working if seleniumwire is not used.

Comment: You can update the question as it looks more of selenium-wire rather than normal selenium/chrome-driver issue- Have a look at open issues in selenium-wire https://github.com/wkeeling/selenium-wire/issues